# Angular reactive form custom validation

Tags: forms, angular5, angular2-forms, reactive

I am trying to make reactive form custom validation, From multiple set of inputs [text-boxes, radio button, select], Form get validated with true when any two input fields are filled or entered.

Answer (score 1):

For custom validation in form , you can set flag by check form control value in if condition and display message in HTML with that flag.

Example:

In the TS file:

```
flag:boolean;
if(this.demoForm.value.phone && this.demoForm.value.pin){
   this.flag=false;
}else{
   this.flag=true
}
```

In HTML file:

```
<span *ngIf='flag'>Your form is invalid</span>
```